# Find the function limit given region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> Consider the value $b$ with $b \in (0, 1)$ and let $D_b$ be the region to the right side of the line $x = b$, but also inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and call $f(b) = \text{Area of }D_b$, by converting to polar coords, calculate $f(b)$. Also  calculate $\lim_{b \to 0} f(b)$ and $\lim_{b \to 1} f(b)$

I see that $ x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \implies r^2 = 1$

So we should have $r = 1$ for the polar bound.

$x = b \implies r\cos(\theta) = b \implies \theta = \arccos(b)$

But I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $|\theta|\le \arccos b$. And the upper limit on $r$ is $1$. What's the lower limit? If you fix a $\theta$, $r$ starts when $r\cos\theta = b$, so $r=b\sec\theta$. Now set up your integral.

Comment: Is $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$? So we will have a double integral with $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$ as the outside integral? Still confused about the inside integral's limit though?

Comment: No, I said that $-\arccos b\le\theta\le\arccos b$. And I told you the limits on the inner integral, too!

Comment: So the limits on the inner will be $b\sec(\theta) \to 1$?

Comment: Yup. You should study more examples.

Comment: what would the function inside the double integral be though? This is a bit confusing, and I would like some help here.

Comment: The area of a region $R$ is given by $\iint_R 1\,dA$. And in polar coordinates, $dA = r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: is there a reason or intuition behind that?

Comment: Sure, think about chopping up the region into little chunks of area $\Delta A_i$. You get the total area by adding up $\sum 1\Delta A_i$.

Comment: Oh nice!, thanks a lot sir

Comment: Nope. For starters, what happens, as your question asks, when $b\to 0^+$ and $b\to 1^-$?

Comment: Ok, I am making a small mistake somewhere It think. As $b \to 0^{+}$ shouldn't we get $f(b) \to \pi/2$? In this case somewhere I made a mistake and I shouldnt be having 2\cos^{-1}(b)$